# Creating an image like a profile pic inside an Alert Dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-image

I am trying to create a profile image inside an Alert Dialog.  Below you will see a pic of the Dialog and the code I am using. This Alert Dialog is inside an Activity. This activity is already getting an image for a license pic

[image: username_dialog screenshot]

**username_dialog.xml**. only containing the code related to the image view and text

```
   <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="288dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/profile_pic"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:background="#CED5E4"
        android:src="@drawable/user_placeholder" />

    <TextView
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:layout_width="145dp"
        android:layout_height="78dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:text="Press the Take Pic button and create your Profile Pic"
        android:layout_weight="0.23">

    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**bDriverRegistrationActivity** code relevant to question.

```
 private ImageButton license_photo;
 private Uri filepath;
 private StorageReference storageRef;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_b_driver_registration);

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

    license_photo = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.license_photo);
    license_photo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intentCamera = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(intentCamera, 0);
        }
    });

    register_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register_btn);
    register_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            attemptLogin(true);
            uploadFile();
        }
    });


} // onCreate
```

**uploadFile()**

```
public void uploadFile() {

    if (filepath != null) {
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Uploading ...");
        progressDialog.show();

        String userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

        StorageReference licenseRef = storageRef.child("drivers").child(userId)
                .child("images/license.jpg");

        licenseRef.putFile(filepath)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File Uploaded", Toast
                                .LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), exception
                                .getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                })

                .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot
                                .getBytesTransferred()) / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();
                        progressDialog.setMessage(((int) progress) + "% Uploaded...");
                    }
                });

    } else {
        // display an error toast
    }

} // uploadFile()
```

**UsernameDialogFragment**

```
public static class UsernameDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        // Get the layout inflater
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

        // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
        // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
        builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.username_dialog, null));

                // Add action buttons ...

                builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.action_register, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public final void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                        // save the username to Firebase and sign in user  ...

                        // ... casting dialog interface to an alert dialog and casting
                        // the result of the findView to an EditText
                        EditText usernameField  = (EditText)((AlertDialog) dialog)
                                .findViewById(username);
                        String username = usernameField.getText().toString();

                        // year
                        EditText yearField = (EditText)((AlertDialog) dialog).findViewById(R.id.year);
                        String year = yearField.getText().toString();

                        // color, make and model
                        EditText cmmField = (EditText)((AlertDialog) dialog).findViewById(R.id.cmm);
                        String cmm = cmmField.getText().toString();

                        // cell
                        EditText cellField = (EditText)((AlertDialog) dialog).findViewById(R.id.cell);
                        String cell = cellField.getText().toString();

                        // license plate no.
                        EditText plateField = (EditText)((AlertDialog) dialog).findViewById(R.id.licenseNo);
                        String licenseNo = plateField.getText().toString();

                        // profile pic
                        ImageView profilePic = (ImageView)((AlertDialog) dialog).findViewById(R.id.profile_pic);
                        profilePic.setImageResource(R.drawable.user_placeholder);



                        // ... get user's unique id
                        String userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

                        User aUser = new User(username, year, cmm, cell, licenseNo);


                        /*  https://android-chat-af94c.firebaseio.com/android-chat-af94c/
                            users/pRsxsToJZPTzCdtft69f1grIJC13/profile/username

                            getInstance -> grabbing the url:
                            https://android-chat-af94c.firebaseio.com/android-chat-af94c/
                        */
                        // above is the same as below ...
                        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("drivers").child(userId).setValue(aUser);

                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getBaseContext(), PoliciesActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }

                });

                builder.setNeutralButton(R.string.action_take_pic, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public final void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, int id) {


                    }
                });

        return builder.create();

    }

} // UsernameDialogFragment
```

**onActivityResult** right now this works with license photo

```
// take photo
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)  {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    filepath = data.getData();

    Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");
    license_photo.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

} // onActivityResult
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you really want to achieve. However, AFAIK, you should save your dialog's `ImageView` to change its image whenever you want:

```
View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.username_dialog, null);
// save imageview as global variable 
ImageView avatar = dialogView.findViewId(R.id.imageview_avatar);
builder.setView(dialogView);
//you can change imageview later after user picks image.
Glide....into(avatar);
```

Comment: I am trying to allow the user to select the take pic button and take a picture and it will replace the image in the image view.  Also, I am using a FragmentDialog.

Comment: yes, do as I suggested above. You have to store the reference to your `ImageView` inside the alertDialog.

Comment: So it doesn't go in the onClick like all the other controls, like the EditTexts and TextViews?

Comment: No, you should `setImage` to the `ImageView` right after inflating the layout resource. The `onClick` callback is called only once when the user clicks on the `positive  Button`. I see in your code, your imageview only changed when you click to the positive button.

Comment: I followed a tutorial and it showed us how to do a fragment dialog in this way.  This is why I chose the other button - neutral button.  How do I get it so that if the user clicks on take pic - how can I get it so the user can take a pic?  I tried your way and nothing happens but crashes the app.

Comment: You can add an `onClickListener` to the `ImageView`, then user can choose to pick an imageview when click to the image.

Comment: isn't that what the onClick in the button is for?  Can you give me an example of code as to what I need to do so that if the user presses the Take Pic button and it allows them to take a pic?

Comment: forgive me, I am new to android.  I created my app in iOS and now trying to create in Android.

Comment: This is what I did:  
View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.username_dialog, null);
            ImageView profilePic = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.profile_pic);
            profilePic.setImageResource(R.drawable.user_placeholder);
            profilePic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    // user picks image
                    
                }
            });
 builder.setView(dialogView);